# I want to print non-english characters on CodeBlocks Windows 7, is there an easy way to I edit the settings?

Tags: c++, utf-8, codeblocks

I want to print out japanese characters in CodeBlocks. There are similar questions related to this one but the answers would seem a bit complicated.

[Is there a simple way to get the number of characters printed in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377045/is-there-a-simple-way-to-get-the-number-of-characters-printed-in-c)

I was wondering whether there's a setting in CodeBlocks where you can change the output to UTF-8 similar with the Save As feature in Notepad.

Comment: Do you want to print the characters using `printf` or do you want to display them inside your code in CodeBlocks?

Comment: I want them to be displayed using the cout command i.e.                                                   string es = "エス" ;                                                   cout << es;